# Aptana Crashes on me Twice a Day

Tags: crash, aptana

I love Aptana, but sadly it crashes on me almost every day. I'm stubbornly sticking with the editor, but if I can find and fix the instability, I will have no major complaints with it.

I'm running Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.9.201202141038 but the crashing has been ongoing ever since I installed Aptana 3 many months and many version upgrades ago.  Following the most recent crash I checked the Aptana .log but there was nothing valuable in there.  There was however quite a bit of info in the OS-X "view details" notification following the crash:  http://pastebin.com/02JrqrUQ

Sometimes it crashes following SVN actions, but also, as most recently, it will crash when it's just sitting there.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how I can address this issue. I believe that I previously
had tried a reinstall which didn't fix the issue, but if no one has anything else to try, I guess I may give that a try again.

Thanks,
Dan

---- UPDATE ---

Ingo, Thanks for the response. That thread on appcelerator.org definitely describes the errors I was seeing.

Following your advice, I upgraded to the Aptana nightlies (now on version 3.1.0) and have not seen a crash in 2 full days. Hopefully any future crashes will now be few and far between and no longer a daily occurence.

Thanks so much for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your information. We've been tracking this issue, but honestly, it's been a bear to diagnose and reproduce, since most of the references don't point to any code of Studio--only the underlying versions:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3682

Please follow along on the linked ticket for more information. You might try the latest nightly (3.1 version) at preview.appcelerator.com which is built on top of Eclipse 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue - and then I could not even open Aptana. Right click on the program -> click Properties -> Compatibility (Windows 7) > and tick "Run this program as an administrator"
This worked for me temporarily - the real fix is to delete or rename the .log file in your workspace.